# How to load new comment after ajax submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I found a light-weighted script for submitting wordpress comments via ajax. It does submitted the comments but can't see the new comment except the comments count got updated. If manually refresh the page, can see it is listed. Here's the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  jQuery.noConflict();
/* the acp_long is removed here. it got printed in page head by php
   acp_lang[]:
   [0]: 'Loading...'
   [1]: 'Please enter your name.'
   [2]: 'Please enter your email address.'
   [3]: 'Please enter a valid email address.'
   [4]: 'Please enter your comment'
   [5]: 'Your comment has been added.'
   [6]: 'ACP error!'
*/
// initialise
var form, err, reply;
function acp_initialise() {
  jQuery('#commentform').after('<div id="error"></div>');
  jQuery('#submit').after('<img src="'+acp_path+'loading.gif" id="loading" alt="'+acp_lang[0]+'" />');
  jQuery('#loading').hide();
  form = jQuery('#commentform');
  err = jQuery('#error');
  reply = false;
}
acp_initialise();

jQuery('.comment-reply-link').live('click', function() {
  // checks if it's a reply to a comment
  reply = jQuery(this).parents('.depth-1').attr('id');
  err.empty();
});

jQuery('#cancel-comment-reply-link').live('click', function() {
  reply = false;
});  

jQuery('#commentform').live('submit', function(evt) {

  err.empty();

if(form.find('#author')[0]) {
  // if not logged in, validate name and email
  if(form.find('#author').val() == '') {
  err.html('<span class="error">'+acp_lang[1]+'</span>');
  return false;
  }
  if(form.find('#email').val() == '') {
  err.html('<span class="error">'+acp_lang[2]+'</span>');
  return false;
  }
  var filter  = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  if(!filter.test(form.find('#email').val())) {
  err.html('<span class="error">'+acp_lang[3]+'</span>');
  if (evt.preventDefault) {evt.preventDefault();}
  return false;
  }
} // end if

if(form.find('#comment').val() == '') {
  err.html('<span class="error">'+acp_lang[4]+'</span>');
  return false;
}

jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({

  beforeSubmit: function() {
  jQuery('#loading').show();
  jQuery('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }, // end beforeSubmit

  error: function(request){
  err.empty();
  var data = request.responseText.match(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/);
  err.html('<span class="error">'+ data[1] +'</span>');
  jQuery('#loading').hide();
  jQuery('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
  return false;
  }, // end error()

  success: function(data) {
  try {
  // if the comments is a reply, replace the parent comment's div with it
  // if not, append the new comment at the bottom
  var response = jQuery("<ol>").html(data);
  if(reply != false) {
  jQuery('#'+reply).replaceWith(response.find('#'+reply));
  jQuery('.commentlist').after(response.find('#respond'));
  acp_initialise();

  } else {//  
  if (jQuery(document).find('.commentlist')[0]) {
  //console.log("find it"); this log line shows it finds the place to append things
  response.find('.commentlist li:last')..hide().appendTo(jQuery('.commentlist')).slideDown('slow');
  } else {
  jQuery('#respond').before(response.find('.commentlist'));
  }
  if (jQuery(document).find('#comments')[0]) {
  jQuery('#comments').html(response.find('#comments'));
  } else {
  jQuery('.commentlist').before(response.find('#comments'));
  }
  }
  form.find('#comment').val('');
  err.html('<span class="success">'+acp_lang[5]+'</span>');
  jQuery('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
  jQuery('#loading').hide();

  } catch (e) {
  jQuery('#loading').hide();
  jQuery('#submit').removeAttr("disabled");
  alert(acp_lang[6]+'\n\n'+e);
  } // end try

  } // end success()

  }); // end ajaxSubmit()

  return false; 

}); // end form.submit()

}); // end document.ready()
```

Any hint in the above code may cause the new comment no showing up?

### Update:

with HMR's help in chatroom, we made test with firebug. The result is:

```
response.find('.commentlist li:last')
Does find the just posed reply and that
jQuery('.commentlist')
Does refer to an existing, visible div element on the page but adding the comment to the div using:
response.find('.commentlist li:last').appendTo(jQuery('.commentlist'));
Doesn't make the newly added comment show up.
```

Many thanks to HMR, but since I made typo error and needed time to clean file. our test stopped.

why the append doesnt work posting the html contained in that ".commentlist" element. We've already proven that when it's empty it works so there is something with the html in there that won't show newly added comments.

Comment: You could try the following, after the line:
    response.find('.commentlist li:last').appendTo(jQuery('.commentlist'));
insert the following line: return;

Maybe something later in the code messes it up. You could also post the output of:
    jQuery('.commentlist');

Preferably one that doesn't contain a lot of comments. If you know about html you might check the html to see if there is a reason why appending the last reply would not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the last line in the console is "find it" could you dump some more values in that part?

```
} else {
   if (jQuery(document).find('.commentlist')[0]) {
       console.log("find it");
       console.log("did it find:",response.find('.commentlistli:last'));
       console.log("adding to:",jQuery('.commentlist'));
```

Comment: The firebug log shows whole html of the post page. I guess it's because the original comment submit action url is to refresh the page

Comment: the log is with "reply is false" at the end.

Comment: The code you posted only does something if the postback is a reply, if not then nothing happens. You also should not end up with a complete page reply. Only the latest posted data should be in the reply (or you'll have the entire page added again inside your page). This is something you need to figure out how to do in wordpress. Could you post the link where you got this code?

Comment: I just updated my question. I moved the log line down to "else" places, it founds the class and appended html. here's the link I downloaded the plugin, the plugin is no longer supported: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/moojax-comment-posting/.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe it's that the just posted element could not be found in the response or that jquery could not find where to append it to. Maybe the animations don't work (.hide() and slideDown('slow')) You could try removing those from the code.

Comment: cut either hide or slidedown or both doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What's the the poutput of the other console.logs I suggested?

Comment: "did it find" is object[] with context: undefined, and a lot of other things. "adding to" is object[ol.commentlist] with context: document and again a lot of other things. what to check in the object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23152/discussion-between-jenny-and-hmr)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your comments are inside an HTML element with a `class="commentlist"`. The line `jQuery('.commentlist').after(response.find('#respond'));` tries to insert the new comment there, if no such element is there it will not work.